# Is there a systematic difference between /a:/ in BrE and /æ:/ in AmE?

Tags: british-english, phonology

so another question I have is that whether it is systematic (a regular pattern) between /a:/ in BrE and /æ:/ in AmE or not.

There are words that a pronounced differently like dance or rather. I have one source which indicates that this contrast is not systematic but restricted to 80 words.

Then there is a passage which I do not understand I cite "For example, while the word pass is pronounced as expected in R.P. (/pa:s/), the word *standard* has /æ/." - So what exactly is meant by standard since it is written in italic. I also though that in Am it is always the /æ:/ pronunciation and BrE always /a:/

I have thought the entire time that there is a systematic phonological difference!

thx,

Comment: In RP, the 'a' in *pass* and the first *'a'* in *standard* are different vowels. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pass?q=pass) [Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/standard?q=standard) labels these vowels /ɑː/ and /a/, so /pɑːs/ and /ˈstandəd/. My guess is that your source is labeling them /a:/ and /æ:/, which is really confusing and probably less correct.

Comment: @PeterShor Oh I am sorry I meant the /ɑ:/ instead of /a/ I forgot to write it in correct IPA! so everywhere were I used /a/ it is actually /ɑ:/!!!!

Comment: :) thanks, I need to read it again since I am a little confused but  I am curious to know if there is a systematic difference or not. :)

Comment: @PeterShor thanks again :) but why does one source say there is no systematic difference while the other does.

Comment: It's systematic if you can *always* decide whether it's /æ/ or /ɑ:/ just by looking at the phonemes in the word. But here you can only guess correctly most of the time; sometimes you'll be wrong. So it's not-quite-systematic. Does that count as systematic or not? It's certainly not true that /æ/ in AmE goes to /ɑ:/ in British English.

Comment: @PeterShor  I would say that there is a systematic difference if it IS /æ/ *AmE = /ɑ:/ *BrE because a non-systematic difference would be leisure or neither (BrE, AmE)

Comment: tim a, what's strange is that the *a* sound in *pass*, in RP, is also used in American pronunciation of the word *pasta*!

Comment: @PeterShor I will try to figure it out by the day after tomorrow and inform you about my findings :)

Comment: [Here](http://dialectblog.com/2011/03/10/mastering-the-trap-bath-split/) is an excellent blog post about this.

Comment: @PeterShor there are many borrowed words that are /ɑ:/ in AmE and /æ/ in BrE.

Comment: @Tristanr I suppose that's because we have more Italian immigrants in America.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer to your question is the change that occurred. By and large, English spelling is conservative and reflects pronunciation from an earlier period.

Here's [Barber, Beal & Shaw](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=_dZKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=%22Before%20the%20voiceless%20fricatives%20/f/%22%20Barber&source=bl&ots=v_M6-cpjbi&sig=O4_wID2g3Phy-_BKD_CZ7PUOv2k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GMSrU7-EOcTKkwWmpIEY&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Before%20the%20voiceless%20fricatives%20%2Ff%2F%22%20Barber&f=false), *The English Language*, 2nd edn., p. 227.

> Before the voiceless fricatives /f/, /s/, and /θ/, short [æ], from ME
>   [Middle English] *a*, became lengthened to [æː], which later became
>   [aː], and then [ɑː]

Hence the RP vowels in *laugh*, *pass* and *path*.

If you listen to Australian English for these words, you'll hear [aː] rather than [ɑː] - in other words, long vowels, but a front rather than a back vowel. The Australian vowel represents the British vowel around the 19th century.

The main point is that [ɑː] is restricted to certain words.